# Why doesn't a CORS preflight request cause another?

Tags: http, cors

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), every [non-simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) is doomed to fall into an infinite recursion:

1. I want to send a non-simple CORS request (with the verb `PUT` e.g.)
2. My browser tries to send a CORS preflight request for the request above because it is a `PUT` which needs to be preflighted. (so far so good)
3. My browser tries to send another CORS preflight request for the request above because the preflight request itself is an `OPTIONS` which needs to be preflighted. (what a terrible failure)
4. My browser tries to send another CORS preflight request for the request above because the preflight request itself is an `OPTIONS` which needs to be preflighted.
5. My browser tries to send another ...

but it isn't and must not. It's obvious that I got it wrong at #3.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think it falls into the [What request use CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#What_requests_use_CORS) part: the preflight CORS request is not part of it, so it's not concerned by using CORS.

Comment: The browser never makes more than one preflight OPTIONS request. If it makes a preflight OPTIONS request that doesn’t succeed, then the browser stops right there and never makes any more requests — including not even trying the PUT request from your code. That behavior is mandated by the CORS protocol requirements (defined in the Fetch spec). In other words, the reason one CORS preflight doesn’t cause another is, the spec says it doesn’t. It’s just not how the CORS protocol works.

Comment: I see. I focused on the verb too much missing out more basic things. Thank you guys!